# Can I disable permanent potion effects in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I accidentally got permanent speed and jump boost on Minecraft, and its really annoying! Is there any way to disable this?

Comment: Did you try to drink milk? That's the best I've got. :P

Comment: Telling us *how* you accidentally got a permanent speed and jump boost might help us help you.

Comment: Do you happen to have an active beacon lying around nearby?

Answer (score 2):

That depends on how you obtained these effects.

If you obtained these effects using a potion or the `/effect` command, then you can drink milk to get rid of them, or use the command `/effect Username clear` to clear all potion effects. In-game testing shows that milk does, in fact, get rid of the speed and jump boost effects; it's not just useful for poisoning.

If you obtained the effects by way of beacon, however, get rid of the beacon or change the effects the beacon gives. Drinking milk will work for a couple of seconds, but the effect quickly replenishes itself.

Comment: What I want to know is how someone *accidentally* gets these effects; you'd need to have created 2 beacons if that was the case, and one can't really accidentally use /effect ...

Comment: Also, to be able to create a beacon and activate it without knowing the effects is just not possible.